# Changing the href of a link in a mustache template with DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument, mustache

I am facing a problem, when I try to change the href of a link in a mustache template using DOMDocument.

Consider the following code:

```
$template = "<a href='{{url}}'>Link</a>";

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($template, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOXMLDECL);

foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) $link->setAttribute('href', 'https://myurl.com?redirect=' . $link->getAttribute('href'));

$template = $document->saveHTML();
echo $template; // <a href='https://myurl.com?redirect=%7B%7Burl%7D%7D'>Link</a>
```

If later I try to render this via mustache, I won't be able ofc because the `{{}}` part was encoded. Is there any way to tell DOMDocument to stop auto validating my href attributes? Or is there any alternative with which I can easily get a html string, find all `<a></a>` elements in it, and change their `href` attribute?

**EDIT:** Obviously this is a simple example, and in my real life scenario it is not a possibility for me, to prerender the HTML with mustache, and replace the links then.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you're looking for all instances of href='{{url}}' and you wish to replace them with href='https://myurl.com?redirect={{url}}'. That's pretty straight forward with regex and preg_replace.

Here is an initial draft of a search string:

```
/(?<=href=')()(?={{url}}.*>)/
```

This regex pattern looks behind for the href=' token, and ahead for the {{url}} followed by arbitrary characters and a closing tag >. The () operator in the middle matches *nothing*. Then, we replace that *nothing* with our url prefix below.

And here the replacement:

```
https://myurl.com?redirect=\1
```

Then, this php code will perform the replace:

```
<?php

$sampleString = "<a href='{{url}}'>Link</a>

<p>This text {{url}} will not get replaced</p>

<a href='{{url}}' download='true'>Another Link</a>"; 

$regex = "/(?<=href=')()(?={{url}}.*>)/"; 

$replaced = preg_replace($regex, "https://myurl.com?redirect=\1", $sampleString); 

echo $replaced;
```

You can see a fiddle for [the regex](https://regex101.com/r/EMr2V9/3) and [the php](https://3v4l.org/LhBUs)

Comment: the `{{url}}` was just an example btw. I am aware that I can do this with regexp, but I am looking for something more failproof, that's why I was looking into dom manipulation.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai https://regex101.com/r/EMr2V9/4 lightens up the strictness on what the mustache tag is...